# Get index in a list based on a condition - C#

Tags: c#

To get the first number which is positive from a list of numbers, I can write:

```
var FirstPostiveNumber = Values.Where(x => x > 0).FirstOrDefault();
```

how do I also get the `index` number at which above condition is true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Select()` override that passes in the index:

```
var FirstPositiveNumber = Values
    .Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
    .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Value > 0);

Console.WriteLine("Value is: {0}", FirstPositiveNumber.Value);
Console.WriteLine("Index is: {0}", FirstPositiveNumber.Index);
```